# Rails 4: Rack SSL enforcer ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR with localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, ruby-on-rails-4, development-environment

I am trying to implement the Rack SSL enforcer and I have added the Gem to my Gemfile 
along with adding the following like to `config/application.rb`:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer
```

When I run `rails s` and go to my localhost I get the ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR message. Is this because I am not supposed to run ssl locally (It does seem somewhat unintuitive but I also would like to just see  if it (The SSL requirement) works before going to production)?

Comment: this post seems to suggest making the requirements for ssl only in ones `production.rb` file as if that is common practice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444780/rails-activating-ssl-support-gets-chrome-confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error message because Webrick (or whatever server you are using) serves HTTP. To serve HTTPS, use `thin` with the `--ssl`option (start two instances to serve both HTTP and HTTPS):

```
thin start --ssl -p 443
thin start -p 80
```